# How to configure MySQL read replica in RDS from Slave server

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, database-replication, rds

We have a working MySQL Master-Slave replication in our Data center. We need to configure one read replica in AWS RDS from my slave server. How can I achieve this? I need the configuration like the following. Read replica should be configured fron Slave Server

Master --> Slave --> Read Replica [In RDS]

Answer (score 0):

This document section seems just right for your requirement :

[Replication with a MySQL or MariaDB Instance Running External to Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.External.Repl.html)

What required is some downtime to your DB. The steps consist of :

1. Make your DB read-only
2. Dump data to the RDS instance
3. Enable writing on your DB again
4. Create user with replication privileges on your DB
5. Start replicating your DB from RDS using the created user

Comment: Tried to establish this our server to RDS replication as per this URL.We have 36 database available in master server and the total size nearly around 300GB and out live application is working to use this master database server. Took the backup of these database and restored it into slave RDS. Getting Slave SQL Running = No error. Can you suggest a solution to enable replication with this big data

Comment: For no-downtime migration, you can try DMS solution from AWS
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/CHAP_MySQL2Aurora.html

Comment: @RoniBaby - did you run the command `CALL mysql.rds_start_replication;` on the slave?

Comment: @qkhanhpro - the downside of DMS is that you have to migrate anything non-data or non-schema yourself. Things like triggers and keys do NOT get migrated using DMS.